# MySQL: on duplicate key update isn't working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table called

---

### FactSales ( ID, dateid, customerid, salesid, salescount)

Here ID is primary key auto increment.

I have also added a unique constraint comprising of columns dateid, customerid and salesid

**My Requirement**: Insert/ Update data on a daily basis using my SP.

**My Problem**: I tried with insert ... on duplicate key update but its not working.

*My complete code here*

```
-- this is creation script for factsales table
CREATE TABLE FactSales 
(
  ID           BIGINT(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  DateID       INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  CustomerID   INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  salesID      INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  salescount   INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

-- adding the unique constraint
ALTER TABLE FactSales ADD UNIQUE KEY uk1 (dateid,customerid,salesid);

-- creating the dummy table for work
DROP TABLE if exists tmpfactsales CREATE TABLE tmpfactsales 
(
  ID           BIGINT(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  DateID       INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  CustomerID   INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  salesID      INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  salescount   INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

-- now I need to get maximum of minimum last entry date of all customers
SELECT MIN(maxdate) INTO @MinMaxDateID
FROM (SELECT a.customerid,
             MAX(a.dateid) AS maxdate
      FROM factsales a
      GROUP BY a..customerID) a;

-- inserting data from min max date into dummy table
INSERT INTO tmpfactsales
(
  dateid,
  customerid,
  salesid,
  Salescount
)
SELECT dateid,
       customerid,
       salesid,
       SUM(salescount) AS salescount
FROM fact_customer_sales
WHERE status = 'active'
-- condition for daily data
AND   dateid >= @minmaxdateid
AND   dateid <= curdate()
GROUP BY dateid,
         customerid,
         salesid;


-- BEGIN Insert update on duplicate key

INSERT INTO FactSales
(
  dateid,
  customerid,
  salesid,
  salescount
)
SELECT dateid,
       customerid,
       salesid,
       salescount
FROM tmpfactsales ON duplicate KEY UPDATE factsales.salescount = tmpfactsales.salescount;
```

**Expected Result**: Update if already exists or else insert new data in the fact sales table. In my case, new records are being added instead.

more details about my data here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/8myHO.png

Comment: Post the exact `create table` statements, so we can verify. You can get those with `show create table foo\G`

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error message? All records are inserted and none gets updated? No error, but no data changes?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem , given your question things behave as they should please add your table definitions and some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question has been solved. I created new tables and somehow it worked with on duplicate key update. Not sure why the problem caused in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t (ID int auto_increment primary key , dateid date, customerid int, salesid int, salescount int);
create table t1 (ID int, dateid date, customerid int, salesid int, salescount int);

alter table t
    add unique key uk1(dateid,customerid,salesid);

insert into t1 values
(1,'2019-04-11',1,1,1),
(1,'2019-04-11',1,1,2);

Insert into t
(
dateid,
customerid, 
salesid,
salescount
)
select dateid,
customerid, 
salesid,
salescount
from t1 -- this is the temp table that has daily data
where t1.salescount = 1 
on duplicate key update t.salescount = t1.salescount;

Insert into t
(
dateid,
customerid, 
salesid,
salescount
)
select dateid,
customerid, 
salesid,
salescount
from t1 -- this is the temp table that has daily data 
where salescount = 2
on duplicate key update t.salescount = t1.salescount;

select * from t;

+----+------------+------------+---------+------------+
| ID | dateid     | customerid | salesid | salescount |
+----+------------+------------+---------+------------+
|  1 | 2019-04-11 |          1 |       1 |          2 |
+----+------------+------------+---------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If this is not a good representation of your data please expand your question to include both table definitions and some sample data.

Comment: Hey Salmon, I have updated my original question with more details. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: I can't cut and paste from images so I will look at this but it will take a bit of time while I retype everything.

Comment: Why do you have a query which references fact_sales when there is no such table defined and why is does the insert use fact_customer_sales which also does not exist?And what do you hope to achiev by comparing an int dateid to currdate?

Comment: My bad on the fact_sales, it was a typo. I have corrected original question as well. And fact_customer_sales does exist. From here the data is to be loaded to factsales table. here is the link for sample data i was able to export. [link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ave_-9o8DQVEbmNJMomoblRX8pE)

Comment: I use linux and don't have excel. If you provide sample data please do so as text or create a sql fiddle.

Comment: Would you please revisit the link i provided again once? I have uploaded csv and txt files of the tables there.

Comment: And regarding comparing dateid to currdate, I am working to create a SP to run at specific time per day to daily incremental load the table, Is my conditions incorrect?

Comment: How come fact_customer_sales does not contain a salesid? and your select min(maxdate) should cater for null values.. BTW one drive no longer available. Until you fix the inconsistencies I'm out.